# программа в с++

Tags: c++

С клавиатуры задаётся слово.Определить сколько раз в веденном слове встречается 'нн'
когда пытаюсь в бить слово на русском выдаёт его какими то иерогливами и подскажите как разбить введённое слово на части по буквы чтобы я смог его подогнать под алгоритм или подскажите алгоритм попроще

Comment: В подобных вопросах далее всегда указывайте ОС и используемую кодировку русского языка.

Comment: Велик могучим русский языка. А.Иванов